# Is there a way for multicolor bordering

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have `td` and it's css is now like this

```
td {
   border-bottom: 3px solid aqua;
}
```

By clicking these cells, I would like to change its color like below pictures.

[image: target picture]

Is there a way to change multi color bordering?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe using [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding upon @king neo's code here. I tried box-shadow: inset, and ::before to give a second line, apart from the border itself, but failed with it. Even border didn't work, because the bottom-border is stumped at the corners, when meeting the border-left and border-right.

All I could think of is to use background with a gradient. This is a fake border though, and any elements inside the td cell will be on top of it. You can fix this with padding, but the table will jump around if you add padding on selection. Therefor, you need to add padding on non-selected rows too.

I also used CSS variables so it's easy to change several things on one place.

```js
var prevRow = null;
function toggle(it) {
  if (it.className.substring(0, 3) == "sel")
    {
    it.className = it.className.substring(3, 6);
     prevRow = null;
     }
  else
    {
    it.className = "sel" + it.className;
    
     if (prevRow != null)
       {
       prevRow.className = prevRow.className.substring(3, 6);
       }
     prevRow = it;
     }
}
```

```css
 :root {
   --color-cyan: #00ffff;
   --color-yellow: #ffff00;
   --border-width: 2px;
 }

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

td {
  padding: var(--border-width);
}

.selodd > td,
.selevn > td {
  --yellow-end-point: var(--border-width);
  --cyan-end-point: calc(2 * var(--border-width));
  --transparent-starting-point: calc(3 * var(--border-width));

  background: linear-gradient(to top,
    var(--color-yellow) var(--yellow-end-point),
    var(--color-cyan) var(--cyan-end-point),
    transparent var(--transparent-starting-point));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table border>
 <tr class="odd" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="evn" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="odd" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="evn" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="odd" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="evn" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

play around this code

```js
var prevRow = null;
function toggle(it) {
  if (it.className.substring(0, 3) == "sel")
    {
    it.className = it.className.substring(3, 6);
     prevRow = null;
     }
  else
    {
    it.className = "sel" + it.className;
    
     if (prevRow != null)
       {
       prevRow.className = prevRow.className.substring(3, 6);
       }
     prevRow = it;
     }
}
```

```css
.odd {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.evn {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.selodd {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.selevn {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table border>
 <tr class="odd" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="evn" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="odd" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="evn" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="odd" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="evn" onclick="toggle(this)">
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
  <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```